# Getting Warning messages in Tabula.py python

Tags: python, csv, pdf, tabula

I am working on project that convert a pdf file to csv using python.  I am using `tabula.py`.  Everything works fine.  I get clear tables in the csv file, but `tabula.py` displays warning messages like this:

```
Nov 08, 2017 10:48:48 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont toUnicode
WARNING: No Unicode mapping for .notdef (9) in font Helvetica.
```

How can I suppress or mute this warning?

Answer (score 0):

When calling `tabula.read_pdf`, add java options:

```py
tables = tabula.read_pdf(xxxxxx, java_options=[
    "-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=off",
    "-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog"
])
```

The output was from java so redirect stdout from python won't work.